# C# & VS error: "make sure that the maximum index on a list is less than the list size"

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, for-loop

I faced the error mentioned in the title when doing my homework, and simply can't find a way to remove it. Here is the method that I have this problem with:

```
public static double LaskeMiidi(double[] luvut)
{
    double ka = Keskiarvo(luvut);
    double miidi = luvut[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < luvut.Length; i++)
    {
        if (luvut[i] - ka < luvut[i + 1] - ka) // The line error points to!
        {
            miidi = luvut[i];
        }
        else
        {
            miidi = luvut[i + 1];
        }
    }
    return miidi;
}
```

So basically the problem is that when I say `luvut[i + 1]`, at some point this index might become more than the length of the array is. I just can't figure out any ways to solve this problem, since I'm only a beginner with programming.

Comment: -snip- Change the `for` loop per the answers.

Comment: hint: the problem can be solved by changing "i < luvut.Length" in some way

Comment: Have you tried `i < luvut.Length-1`

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - I'd switch the two clauses or else you still might get the error (due to short circuit evaluation).

Comment: @Tim: Definitely, good call.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: Then it will fall into the `else` block - and fail there too...

Comment: Ah, I missed it there. Well, let's just stick to changing to the `for` loop then.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is the problem:

```
for (int i = 0; i < luvut.Length; i++)
{
    if (luvut[i] - ka < luvut[i + 1] - ka)
```

When `i` is `luvut.Length - 1`, then `i + 1` will be `luvut.Length` - and therefore an invalid index. (For an array of length `x`, the valid indexes are `0` to `x - 1` inclusive.) You probably want to end one iteration earlier:

```
for (int i = 0; i < luvut.Length - 1; i++)
```

That way `i + 1` will still be a valid index in the array - both in the `if` condition and in the body of the `else` clause.

Comment: Beat me to it .. as per usual! :)

Answer (score 0):

End your loop earlier:

```
for (int i = 0; i < luvut.Length - 1; i++)
```

This stops the loop ever getting to the point where an index would be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that when you define an array, range of items are between 0 and `array.length-1`. so you should write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < luvut.Length-1; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

When `i = luvut.Length -1`, `luvut[i + 1]` will give an error as it is beyond the array bounds.

You need either:

```
for (int i = 0; i < luvut.Length - 1; i++)
```

Or else handle the `luvut[i + 1]` issue in another way in another If block.